# Como desarrollar una función que debe calcular la suma de numeros pares hasta N

Tags: python

Debo crear una función que sume solamente los numeros pares hasta el número N designado.

por ejemplo 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10... + N

Si N es 6 debe de sumar: 2 + 4 + 6 = 12

Comment: existe fórmula para eso :/

Comment: Si pero debo hacerlo sin ella

Comment: `sum(x for x in range(2, n + 2, 2))`

Comment: Bienvenido, es muy importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo mediante un bucle, en este caso `while`, en el que se sumará 2 por cada iteración hasta llegar al número que se ha pasado por un `input`.
Este resultado se agrega a una lista y luego con ayuda de la función `sum` sumamos todos los elementos de la lista lo que nos dará el resultado.

```
num=0

num_obtenidos=[]

rango=input('introduzca hasta que numero quiere sumar: ')

while num < int(rango):
    num+=2
    num_obtenidos.append(num)
    

listSum = sum(num_obtenidos)
print(num_obtenidos)
print(f"Suma de los numeros -> {listSum}")
```

Comment: No necesitas crear una lista para hacer la suma. Consume memoria en forma innecesaria.

Comment: soy nuevo en esto, fue la forma conocida mas facil que se me ocurrio :)

Comment: Es importante agregar una explicaciòn de como resuelve el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisar [answer], saludos,